# Python equivalent of C++ member pointer

Tags: python, pointers, member

What would be the equivalent of a C++ member pointer in Python? Basically, I would like to be able to replicate similar behavior in Python:

```cpp
// Pointer to a member of MyClass
int (MyClass::*ptMember)(int) = &MyClass::member; 

// Call member on some instance, e.g. inside a function to 
// which the member pointer was passed 
instance.*ptMember(3)
```

Follow up question, what if the member is a property instead of a method? Is it possible to store/pass a "pointer" to a property without specifying the instance?

One way would obviously be to pass a string and use `eval`. But is there a cleaner way?

**EDIT:** There are now several really good answers, each having something useful to offer depending on the context. I ended up using what is described in my answer, but I think that other answers will be very helpful for whoever comes here based on the topic of the question. So, I am not accepting any single one for now.

Comment: @Dan, you are welcome to propose a solution that would allow me to do it by embedding C++ code into my python app :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a Python class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 42

    def fn(self):
        return self.x
```

The equivalent of a C++ pointer-to-memberfunction is then this:

```
fn = MyClass.fn
```

You can take a method from a class (`MyClass.fn` above) and it becomes a plain function! The only difference between function and method is that the first parameter is customarily called `self`!  So you can call this using an instance like in C++:

```
o = MyClass()
print(fn(o)) # prints 42
```

However, an often more interesting thing is the fact that you can also take the "address" of a bound member function, which doesn't work in C++:

```
o = MyClass()
bfn = o.fn
print(bfn()) # prints 42, too
```

Concerning the follow-up with the properties, there are plenty answers here already that address this issue, provided it still is one.

Comment: My usecase prevents me from having address of a bound method in the first place, but your suggestion `fn(o)` does indeed seem like the most elegant way of having a member pointer to a Python method. This is quite similar to the `MethodType` approach, but cleaner if you don't need to pass around the bound method afterwards.

Comment: I can't imagine what you're doing there; In my experience, I always needed the bound version, so that I had to use SigC++, Boost.Bind or later C++11 and bind the function to the object. Still, interesting, thanks for the feedback! BTW, in Python, functions and classes are first-class objects. That means that you can attach a function to a class and it becomes a method for all instances. Also, you can take a method from a class (`MyClass.fn` above) and it becomes a plain function! The only difference between function and method is that the first parameter is customarily called `self`!

Answer (score 4):

The closest fit would probably be [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import attrgetter
foo_member = attrgetter('foo')
bar_member = attrgetter('bar')
baz_member = attrgetter('baz')

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 2

    def baz(self):
        return 3

example_object = Example()
print foo_member(example_object) # prints 1
print bar_member(example_object) # prints 2
print baz_member(example_object)() # prints 3
```

`attrgetter` goes through the exact same mechanism normal dotted access goes through, so it works for anything at all you'd access with a dot. Instance fields, methods, module members, dynamically computed attributes, whatever. It doesn't matter what the type of the object is, either; for example, `attrgetter('count')` can retrieve the `count` attribute of a list, tuple, string, or anything else with a `count` attribute.

---

For certain types of attribute, there may be more specific member-pointer-like things. For example, for instance methods, you can retrieve the unbound method:

```
unbound_baz_method = Example.baz
print unbound_baz_method(example_object) # prints 3
```

This is either the specific function that implements the method, or a very thin wrapper around the function, depending on your Python version. It's type-specific; `list.count` won't work for tuples, and `tuple.count` won't work for lists.

For properties, you can retrieve the property object's `fget`, `fset`, and `fdel`, which are the functions that implement getting, retrieving, and deleting the attribute the property manages:

```
example_bar_member = Example.bar.fget
print example_bar_member(example_object) # prints 2
```

We didn't implement a setter or deleter for this property, so the `fset` and `fdel` are `None`. These are also type-specific; for example, if `example_bar_member` handled lists correctly, `example_bar_member([])` would raise an `AttributeError` rather than returning `2`, since lists don't have a `bar` attribute.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the existence of `operator.attrgetter`. It looks like an elegant alternative to what I have in my answer. I still prefer just getting a reference to an unbound method, although for properties `attrgetter` does seem like a superior way which does not require using `.fget` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I was not satisfied with the string approach and did some testing. This seems to work pretty well and avoids passing strings around:

```
import types

# Our test class
class Class:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val

    def method(self):
        return self._val

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._val

# Get the member pointer equivalents
m = Class.method
p = Class.prop

# Create an instance
c1 = Class(1)

# Bind the method and property getter to the instance
m1 = types.MethodType(m, c1)
p1 = types.MethodType(p.fget, c1)

# Use
m1()  # Returns 1
p1()  # Returns 1

# Alternatively, the instance can be passed to the function as self
m(c1)  # Returns 1
p.fget(c1)  # Returns 1
```

Comment: While this probably gives an approximation of c++ pointers, this doesn't seem very pythonic, and to use the language like this isn't that common. So now that you figured out how to do it, you should ask yourself.... Should you do it? ;)

Comment: @Dan So, using `__getattribute__` or `eval` is more Pythonic in your opinion?

Comment: And by more Pythonic I don't mean "can be done only in python" but rather "is the better way of doing it in python" :)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that this was worse than `__getattribute__`. When I referred to whether you "should" reproduce this feature, I just meant that sometimes we need to ask ourselves why doesn't the language have it built in already, and if its not built in, am I doing something the "hard" way. (obviously everything in C++ is the hard way though) haha. If you really want to do it though, I think either your approach or `__getattribute__` are solid, although more people will be familiar with `__getattribute__`, since its built in.

Comment: The only gripe I have about this answer (which gets closer to my answer the longer I look at it --- I should reload more often) is the `types.MethodType(m, c1)`.  If you already have a reference to the instance (`c1` in this case), you can get a reference to most members of that instance with a simple `c1.method`.  I say "most" because properties (by design) are too slippery to grab so easily...  at least, through an instance reference.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase, I'm not sure I understand your point. If I knew beforehand what instance the pointer will be used on, then yes. My situation is that I need to separate information about the instance and the method and combine them only later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C++ programmer, so maybe I'm missing some detail of method pointers here, but it sounds like you just want a reference to a function that's defined inside a class.  (These were of type `instancemethod` in Python 2, but are just type `function` in Python 3.)

The syntax will be slightly different --- instead of calling it like a method with `object.reference(args)`, you'll call it like a function: `reference(object, args)`.  `object` will be the argument to the `self` parameter --- pretty much what the compiler would have done for you.

Despite the more C-like syntax, I think it still does what you wanted...  at least when applied to a callable member like in your example.  It *won't* help with a non-callable instance field, though:  they don't exist until after `__init__` runs.

Here's a demonstration:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import math


class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return

    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + str(self.x) + ', ' + str(self.y) + ')'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + str(self)

    def magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)


def print_dict_getter_demo():
    print('Demo of member references on a Python dict:')
    dict_getter = dict.get
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'z': 26}
    print('Dictionary d      :  ' + str(d))
    print("d.get('a')        :  " + str(d.get('a')))
    print("Ref to get 'a'    :  " + str(dict_getter(d, 'a')))
    print("Ref to get 'BOGUS':  " + str(dict_getter(d, 'BOGUS')))
    print('Ref to get default:  ' + str(dict_getter(d, 'BOGUS', 'not None')))
    return


def print_vector_magnitude_demo():
    print('Demo of member references on a user-defined Vector:')
    vector_magnitude = Vector.magnitude
    v = Vector(3, 4)
    print('Vector v        :  ' + str(v))
    print('v.magnitude()   :  ' + str(v.magnitude()))
    print('Ref to magnitude:  ' + str(vector_magnitude(v)))
    return

def print_vector_sorting_demo():
    print('Demo of sorting Vectors using a member reference:')
    vector_magnitude = Vector.magnitude
    v0 = Vector(0, 0)
    v1 = Vector(1, 1)
    v5 = Vector(-3, -4)
    v20 = Vector(-12, 16)
    vector_list = [v20, v0, v5, v1]
    print('Unsorted:  ' + str(vector_list))
    sorted_vector_list = sorted(vector_list, key=vector_magnitude)
    print('Sorted:    ' + str(sorted_vector_list))
    return


def main():
    print_dict_getter_demo()
    print()
    print_vector_magnitude_demo()
    print()
    print_vector_sorting_demo()
    return


if '__main__' == __name__:
    main()
```

When run with Python 3, this produces:

```
Demo of member references on a Python dict:
Dictionary d      :  {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'z': 26}
d.get('a')        :  1
Ref to get 'a'    :  1
Ref to get 'BOGUS':  None
Ref to get default:  not None

Demo of member references on a user-defined Vector:
Vector v        :  (3, 4)
v.magnitude()   :  5.0
Ref to magnitude:  5.0

Demo of sorting Vectors using a member reference:
Unsorted:  [Vector(-12, 16), Vector(0, 0), Vector(-3, -4), Vector(1, 1)]
Sorted:    [Vector(0, 0), Vector(1, 1), Vector(-3, -4), Vector(-12, 16)]
```

As you can see, it works with both builtins and user-defined classes.

**Edit:**

The huge demo above was based on an assumption:  that you had a reference to the class, and that your goal was to "hold on to" to one of the class's methods for use on whatever instances of that class showed up sometime later.

If you already have a reference to the *instance*, it's much simpler:

```python
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'z': 26}
d_getter = d.get
d_getter('z')  # returns 26
```

This is basically the same thing as above, only after the transformation from a `function` into a `method` has "locked in" the argument to `self`, so you don't need to supply it.

Comment: Your assumption was correct. I do want to hold reference to the method to use it on some other instance later. However, your demo could probably be simplified :) Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this in python is to use `__getattribute__`. If you have the name of an attribute, which would be the analog of the c++ pointer-to-member, you could call `a.__getattribute__(x)` to get the attribute whose name is stored in x. It's strings and dicts instead of offsets & pointers, but that's python.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a really good alternative to `eval` if you happen to have a string with the method name. Still, due to my C++ bias, I will probably always find not using strings in such context more pretty :)